# openlayers 3-4 regression tile visualization

Tags: regression, openlayers, openlayers-3

In openlayers 3.19.1 setting up a map like this (replace CUSTOMURL, CUSTOMX, CUSTOMY with real value), assuming that tiles are only available up to level 17:

```
  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        preload: Infinity,
        source: new ol.source.XYZ({
          url: 'http://CUSTOMURL/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
        })
      })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [CUSTOMX, CUSTOMY],
      zoom: 18
    })
  });
```

properly produces a map with tiles at zoom 17 resampled to zoom 18.
With all subsequent version (also last stable version 4.1.0) an empty map is displayed.
Thanks for any help and sorry for my english....

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that in the most recent versions (tested v4.1.0) the tiles are displayed correctly by setting the maxZoom option to the highest level that the tiles are available (17 in the example). The maxZoom option must also be set for vector tiles (..... createXYZ ({maxZoom: ......}).
**This is not a real regression.**
However, in the documentation, the default value of 18 that is declared for the maxZoom option, according to my tests, is not actually applied.